# Mocking Guzzle HTTP Streams using Codeception

Tags: php, unit-testing, guzzle, codeception, mockery

I'm trying to Mock a Stream using GuzzleHttp and Codeception.

Basically, my code is:

```
$response = $this->client->request('GET', $requestPath, $requestBody, $headers);
$response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Where `$this->client->request()` is a method coming from `GuzzleClientService`.

I am expecting the following responses from the GuzzleHttp:

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Laura",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "prospectId": 6352,
        "email": "testing91415846146512@yopmail.com",
        "phone": null
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Leah",
        "lastName": "null",
        "prospectId": 6353,
        "email": "qa41585320231@yopmail.com",
        "phone": null
    },
    {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "prospectId": 6377,
        "email": "qa41586956235@yopmail.com",
        "phone": null
    }
]
```

How should I mock `getBody()` and `getContents()`? And what should it output for both?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to mock; the http transaction, or the http response?  Guzzle provides the `MockHandler` specifically for mocking the transaction.  Why mock a response when the cost of just creating one is so low?  Have you viewed any of the test cases for any of Guzzle's handlers?

Comment: I was able to test it out. I mocked the StreamInterface, ResponseInterface, and I think my last problem was the arguments for the request... it didn't match.